# java servlet download file in specific directory

Tags: java, html, servlets, download

I would like to know if it's possible to download a file from a servlet and directly save it in a specific directory on the client (without asking the user to select a directory where to save the file, without prompting anything actually)?

Comment: ok sorry, didn't know that a little courtesy was platitude and that we had to treat each other as machines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, That will break the security, by the way how would server know about the client file system ?

Comment: The only thing you can do is suggest a filename with the Content-Disposition header. You can't force the directory or disable prompting.

Comment: sorry that everybody is not as good as you Andrew... next time don't post this kind of thought, it's only noise and doesn't help the cause... ;)